# importlib: How to import multiple Python files without caring about module names

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module, cpython, python-importlib

I want to use the CPython C API to load Python files as plugins from a C application. Those Python files contain classes and other stuff and I know how to get those once I have the module object.

The current solution I have to import a Python file and get the module object is this (Python 3):

```
import importlib

module = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('some_module', '/path/to/file.py').load_module()
```

I can do the equivalent with the C API.

What I understand is that the module object also gets added to the `sys.modules` dictionary with the key `some_module`.

My problem is that, if I load a second module, also specifying `some_module` as the module name, the names found in the second module are appended to the same loaded module as the first one, and existing names are overwritten! That is, in this case:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('some_module', '/path/to/file.py').load_module()
module2 = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('some_module', '/path/to/file2.py').load_module()
```

`module` and `module2` are actually the same object. In my case this is bad because both plugins can (and will) have the same global names.

Note that the user of my application can specify a list of paths from which to load plugin files, so Python files can be located at different places, which also means that two different plugins can have the same base name.

Knowing this, is my only option to create a unique module name from the path? Then the last example becomes:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('path_to_file', '/path/to/file.py').load_module()
module2 = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('path_to_file2', '/path/to/file2.py').load_module()
```

Is there any way to *not* care about the actual module names when importing?

Comment: Not completely sure (never done this), but I think this is not possible if you allow loading from multiple places. Do you have dependencies between the modules, i.e. "/path/to/file.py" imports "/path/to/file2.py"? Note, that I think this case is impossible to get working :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can make concurrent versioning of modules (plugins) for import of the same. another way is interrogate folder where modules are and sort them (some sort of workflow pattern) and remove duplicates if they exist.
In general import machinery should not care about what you want! it is micro pattern and assumes that you will prep harness for loading.
I have above in all my applications and love the fact i get all wiring in place to load what ever i desire and spectrum is incredible, from command line to full blown ML pipelines...